# Websocket compressed bit must be 0

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, node-http-proxy

I have this setup:
User goes to my domain, behind this domain is an instance of a node-http-proxy server. The node-http-proxy server proxies the http request to one of my servers. The servers are using express and socket.io to serve as a chat service.

The request gets trough to one of my servers. Socket.io and express respond as they should (sending html and socket.io client). Then, a handshake is attempted, but fails with `Compressed bit must be 0 if no negotiated deflate-frame extension`

Is there something wrong in my setup? Without the node-http-proxy server in between, everything works fine.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to be working, but I haven't changed any code...